# Position div B on top of div A

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

Hi I'm struggling with this issue.

**Desktop:**

> Div A
>
> Div B

But in responsive the `div`s have to change their position like this:

**Responsive:**

> Div B
>
> Div A

I made a [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9wu15v3z/):

```css
#a {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

#b {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  div 1
</div>
<div id="b">
  div2
</div>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you just want the green one above the red one? Explain your question @pandaNine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [**`grid-row`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row) from CSS grid layout

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, auto)
}

#a {
  background-color: red;
}

#b {
  background-color: green;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  #b {
    grid-row: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="a">
    div 1
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    div2
  </div>
</section>
```

---

**Alternatives:**

- use `order` with also CSS grid layout

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, auto)
}

#a {
  background-color: red;
}

#b {
  background-color: green;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  #b {
    order: -1
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="a">
    div 1
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    div2
  </div>
</section>
```

- use `column-reverse` from flexbox layout <sub>(as suggested by @G-Cyr in comments below)</sub>

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
}

#a {
  background-color: red;
}

#b {
  background-color: green;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  section {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="a">
    div 1
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    div2
  </div>
</section>
```

- use `flex-wrap/wrap-reverse` with flexbox layout

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  flex: 0 100%
}

#a {
  background-color: red;
}

#b {
  background-color: green;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  section {
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="a">
    div 1
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    div2
  </div>
</section>
```

- use `order` with flexbox layout

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
}

#a {
  background-color: red;
}

#b {
  background-color: green;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  #b {
    order: -1
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="a">
    div 1
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    div2
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: you also have flex-flow:column-reverse ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to support older browsers, you can do it this way as well.  But this only works if the elements have a fixed height, otherwise you will have to play some other games.

```css
#a {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

#b {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  #a {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
  }
  #b {
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  div 1
</div>
<div id="b">
  div2
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer with 2 selector and a single rule :`transform:scale(-1);`

```css
  /* target the container and its direct-child */

div,
div>* {
  transform: scale(-1);
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  div,
  div>* {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  #a del {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  #a ins {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 id="a">HTML Ipsum Present<del>s</del><ins>ed</ins></h1>
  <p id="b"><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci,
    sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>
</div>
```